# The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\rc.exe" /r "C:\InteropUserControl.rc" @echo." exited with code 3

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

I am trying to build a VB.NET project.

I am getting this error

```
The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\rc.exe" /r "C:\InteropUserControl.rc" @echo." exited with code 3.
```

I think the problem is that this file does not exist on my computer:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\rc.exe
```

Instead, I found it for example here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86
```

The vbproj shows this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\rc.exe" /r "$(ProjectDir)InteropUserControl.rc"
@echo.</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But I am not sure what to write there instead.

I have tried and changed it to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\rc.exe
```

But that did not help.

I have also copied rc.exe and rc.dll from here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\
```

to here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE
```

but it didn't change anything.

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the InteropFormToolKit directory, there was a file to found named "Source\Source.zip".

I unzipped these files, and with them, all went fine.
No more rc.exe errors.